# Add Progress % to SQL Query in C#

Tags: c#, progress

I have a SQL query that is going to be returning a large data set from a database table (over a million records), is there a way to create a Progress indicator in C# if I'm using SQL Data Client to execute the queries?  I also need to do this same thing for a MERGE (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) query that could take some time.  Is this possible in a Console App or Windows Forms app?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just make the call async so your UI is not tied up.  Then you can alert the user (maybe a toast notification) that the job is completed?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Now what's your next question?

Comment: [Why “is it possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: You can only report the percentage progress on something you can measure.  Can you measure the progress of the query?  (And of course, if it takes a long time, perhaps the place to start is optimizing the query or the code running it so the user need not be distracted from that fact.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving "over a million records", something in your data retreival and/or processing is very wrong.

The average human can not process more then 5-50 colums of data (and 50 only if those are 2-3 row colums). So you will never be able to even display all that data. If you can not dispaly it, you should not retreive it. And that is all asuming your RAM can handle that amount of data. You should look if your DBMS of choice supprots Paging of a results.

I doubt you can actualyl do progress reporting on that detail level with SQLDataClient. However I do not know that class, so it might actually have support for it. Generally this level of progress reporting requires:

- Code that is designed for it
- Code that you have to write yourself, down to the lowest loop doign the retreival (to report between itterations)